# Google calendar API android "GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, calendar, google-calendar-api

I've been trying to get a basic project from the samples from Google running for a few hours now. I've followed every step so far and not really changed anything from what it's told me but after importing all the libraries and pasting the default code the program is complaining.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
AccessTokenResponse cannot be resolved to a type    MainActivity.java      line 63  Java Problem
```

Some others are reported missing like. `GoogleAccessProtectedResource`, `GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant`, `GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl`.

From the default code of

```
// Step 1: Authorize -->
    String authorizationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(clientId, redirectUrl, scope)
        .build();
```

The fact this is not working is obviously leading to assume it's something to do with oauth2.

I'm pretty new to fiddling around with Android and Java, but after reading around I did manually import the libraries via right clicking > properties > java build path.

I've imported all the ones it said to import and cannot understand why it is erroring on practically the first step.

This is what I've imported.

Libraries:

[image: libs]

All I want to do is view a public calendar in the Android Application. Been so much bother to get this API working

The code that I'm looking at for setting this up is found [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using the basic Java library (which was not built for Android) rather than the Android provided [Calendar Provider API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)?

Comment: Hey man, yeah well I had a previous question and some guy said to use the the api like that, I went through the tutorials and just assumed it would work out. Obviously not. 

I have tried to work with the Calendar Provider API. I have it showingthe device's calendar with the currently logged in Google account. But I couldn't work out how to view the public calendar via the Calendar Provider API. Would be even better if you had any idea how to do it via that, as I had some code written already that actually worked. heh. I've never done Java before so android java/java yeah..

Comment: The other question is what I had [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665862/how-to-view-a-public-google-calendar-via-an-android-application) Just wondering, would I have to use that sync adapter thing as it mentions with the ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL? or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am facing the same issue with other classes of the client library, particularly with the `GoogleAccessProtectedResource` class.

From what I found out `GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl` is not being used any more in the latest versions instead of that you should try to use `GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl` which is found in the following package
`com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;`