# How to read public Google Calendar in Android app

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I want to read a public Google Calendar in my Android app, but all the other questions I found didn't give me a solution. I tried using the Java Quickstart sample that Google provides [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java), but I got an error saying that java.awt.Desktop can't be found. How can I get this API to work on Android?

Answer (score 1):

First, the package `java.awt.Desktop` is not available on Android devices, this is more for desktop operating systems (Windows, Linux, etc.)

And then look at this post by *user1406716* who already provided a solution for importing Google Calendar to Android apps:

[How to view a public Google Calendar via an Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665862/how-to-view-a-public-google-calendar-via-an-android-application)